# Query how often an event occurred at a given time

Tags: mysql, sql

**[Aim]**
We would like to find out how often an event "A" ocurred before time "X". More concretely, given the dataset below we want to find out the count of the prior purchases.

**[Context]**
DMBS: MySQL 5.6
We have following dataset:

```
user | date               
1    | 2015-06-01 17:00:00
2    | 2015-06-02 18:00:00
1    | 2015-06-03 19:00:00
```

**[Desired output]**

```
user | date                  | purchase count
1    | 2015-06-01 17:00:00   | 1
2    | 2015-06-02 18:00:00   | 1
1    | 2015-06-03 19:00:00   | 2
```

**[Already tried]**
We managed to get the count on a specific day using an inner join on the table itself.

**[Problem(s)]**
- How to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using user defined variable which is faster as already mentioned in the previous answer.
This needs creating incremental variable for each group depending on some ordering. And from the given data set its `user` and `date`.

Here how you can achieve it

```
select 
user,
date,
purchase_count
from (
  select *, 
  @rn:= if(@prev_user=user,@rn+1,1) as purchase_count,
  @prev_user:=user
  from test,(select @rn:=0,@prev_user:=null)x
  order by user,date
)x
order by date;
```

Change the table name `test` to your actual table name

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32232/12

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient way is to use variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@u = user, @rn + 1,
                  if(@u := user, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as purchase_count;
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @u := '') params
order by user, date ;
```

You can also do this with correlated subqueries, but this is probably faster.